# Zend Layout and Bootstrapping

Tags: zend-framework

So i'm using the standard Zend Layout for my site. I have a number of custom controllers and views, and the content of these pages is displayed, but the details in the head element of the layout.phtml are not shown. Do i need to manually associate the Zend_Layout with each specific controller?. I expected since the layout is loaded via the bootstrap this should be available for free.

My app.ini file has

```
# layout
resources.layout.layoutPath = APPLICATION_PATH "/layouts/scripts"
resources.layout.layout = "layout"
#resources.view[] =

# Views
resources.view.encoding = "UTF-8"
resources.view.basePath = APPLICATION_PATH "/views/"
```

my layout.phtml

```
<?php echo $this->doctype() ?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> 
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /> 
  <?php echo $this->headTitle() ?>
  <?php echo $this->jQuery();?>
</head> 
<!-- application/layouts/scripts/layout.phtml -->
<body>
        <div id="content">
            <?php echo $this->layout()->content ?> 
        </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Give us the path to your layout. Is it really under layouts/scripts?

Comment: (not sure) APPLICATION_PATH "/default/layouts/scripts"

Answer (score 1):

I am using the following in my Initializer.

```
    Zend_Layout::startMvc(array(
        'layoutPath' => $this->_root .  '/application/phpancake/layouts',
        'layout' => 'main'
    ));
```

_root is the  path to the directory where the *application* folder resides.
*phpancake* is the module name (yours is probably *default*).
*layouts* is the directory under which resides my layout file *main.phtml*

Comment: On which initializer, should I place this?

Comment: I am asking which method like if i use you code at `_initLayout()` method, it will give a blank page.